# Why the following code use String and StringBuffer in the same line?

Tags: java, stringbuffer

```
set.add(new String(s) + (ch == 0 ? "" : ch) + new StringBuffer(new String(s)).reverse());
```

I encountered this code from written by someone. It is java code.
s is a char[].
set is a String set.
So why does he use String and then StringBuffer?

Comment: `String` doesn't  have a `reverse` method, but `StringBuffer` does.

Comment: Why not use StringBuilder? It is faster for single-threaded program.

Comment: Depending on the context, could be need of thread safety

Comment: The real reason that they use String and StringBuffer is that the author never bothered to learn about the Apache StringUtils class,
which provides a reverse method that is null save and does not use a synchronized
class (StringBuffer).

Your take away from that code:
Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Cut and paste programmer?

Comment: My first look gives me an instinct of code smell

Comment: @Amethystx87 - given `new StringBuffer(...)` - that StringBuffer can't possibly be used by any other thread, even if this code is being simultaneously executed in multiple threads.

Comment: This is some code from a leetcode question. One solution is this.

Answer (score 1):

`String` has a constructor which takes an array of chars, hence why they create a `new String` first.

Then to reverse the String, they create a `StringBuffer` to use a built in reverse function in order to not implement their own. `StringBuffer`'s constructor takes a String, hence why a `String` is made first and then a `StringBuffer`

Answer (score 0):

Let's split the 3 parts on 3 lines to compare:

```
set.add(
  new String(s) 
+ (ch == 0 ? "" : ch) 
+ new StringBuffer(new String(s)).reverse()
);
```

#### Rewritten

It is equivalent with

```
String trimZero = ch == 0 ? "" : String.valueOf(ch);
set.add(String.valueOf(s) + trimZero + StringUtils.reverse(s));
```

Well, using Apache's [`StringUtils.reverse()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#reverse-java.lang.String-).

If `s` is a `String` it can simply added as is, for example, in an alternative way (to emphasize the different structures):

```
if (ch == 0) {
   set.add(s + StringUtils.reverse(s));
} else {
   set.add(s + String.valueOf(ch) + StringUtils.reverse(s));
}
```

#### Output wise

For example:

- `alphabet`  gets added as `alphabet8tebahpla` (for coincidence `ch` is a non-zero integer).
- `an` gets added as `anna` (given that `ch == 0`)

#### Abbreviations and naming-conventions

When guessing the types I would say:

- `ch` probably is a primitive `char`, array of that, or `CharSequece`
- `s` most-likely is a `String` (rather than the rarely used `short` integer)

Usually abbreviations in symbols/names are ambiguous and can be considered a code-smell.

However there seems to be a historical and accepted convention or habit, especially for *temporary / looping variables* like:

- `int i`
- `String s`
- `char ch`

The *Java Pocket Guide, 4th Edition by Robert Liguori, Patricia Liguori*, [Chapter 1. Naming Conventions](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-pocket-guide/9781491938683/ch01.html#temp_loop_vars_table0) assorted them in a table:

> Temporary variable names may be single letters such as i, j, k, m, and n for integers and c, d, and e for characters. Temporary and looping variables may be one-character names as shown in Table 1-1.

Even core Java methods have such (ambiguous) abbreviated parameter-names

- if the method-context is obvious enough
- that the contents and purpose of the parameter is self-explaining

E.g. [`String.contains(CharSequence s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: This is good answer about good code conventions.